# Validation failed due to UIBackgroundModes key issue

Tags: xcode

In submitting an app to the app store, validation fails with the message: "The UIBackgroundModes key contains an invalid value:". I am not attempting to run anything in the background. I am using the AudioSoundServices to play very short audio files within the app. I've even deleted the key from the info.plist to no avail.

typical coding is shown here:

```
NSString *soundFileX = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"wav"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFileX], &soundIDX);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundIDX);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't your code that is the problem; it's the *Info.plist* setting for the UIBackgroundModes key (presumably).

I suppose it's just possible that Apple is misdescribing the issue and that what they'd really like is for you to play the sound properly using e.g. an AVAudioSession and an AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had a timer that was running in background mode. I set the info.plist file key to not allow background running.

Comment: How were you getting a timer to run in the background? And what as the info.plist key? Was I right that you had a background mode of some sort?